# Using roslyn for hover over data for source tree symbols

Tags: c#, intellisense, roslyn

QUESTION:
How do I apply my personal DocumentationProvider to source tree symbols? Which is the type of symbol i get when i use the SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPosition()

Specifically I want to override the GetDocumentationForSymbol() function.  I have it overridden for my autocomplete symbols but not the symbols i get from hover over.

BACKGROUND:

Hi, I am using roslyn to gather intellisense for a text editor i am creating.  One of the things i need to make is quick info or tool tips. I have it working for the autocomplete suggestions.  by using a snippet that looks like this

```
   compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
        "MyIntellisense",
        new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(dotNetCode) },
        assemblies
    .Select(i => MetadataReference
    .CreateFromFile(i.Location, MetadataReferenceProperties.Assembly,
    new DotNetDocumentationProvider(
    new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
```

this uses my own personal DotNetDocumentationProvider which parses XML and documentation the way I need it.  This works for assembly symbols which are the types of symbols I have when i use Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPosition().

EDIT:  Just wanted to give more background :)

I get symbols in two different ways.

1) One way is when I call

```
var symbols = Recommender.GetRecommendedSymbolsAtPosition(semanticModel, offset, solution.Workspace);
```

I use this when the user asks for auto-complete information
With these symbols I can go through and for each one call:

```
var information = symbol.GetDocumentationCommentXml();
```

This eventually calls a function I have overridden from the class DocumentationProvider :

```
protected override string GetDocumentationForSymbol(string documentationMemberID, CultureInfo preferredCulture, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

2) The second way is for when the user hovers over

```
var symbol = SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPosition(semanticModel, offset, workspace, cancellationToken);
```

I call the exact same function (from the same line of code actually, keeping it 
DRY)

```
var information = symbol.GetDocumentationCommentXml();
```

But this does not invoke my overridden GetDocumentationCommentXml() instead the default Roslyn one is called.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the standard provider?

Comment: Which symbols are failing?

Comment: We want to expose the documentation via quickinfo in our editor intellisense.  The problem is that our source code is dynamically generated from a templated language (like ASP.NET) and consequently contains a bunch of synthetic namespaces, class names, and other things that should not be exposed to the end user who is coding against the original templated source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not finding all of the symbols I need,How to find more symbols using the Roslyn API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441888/not-finding-all-of-the-symbols-i-need-how-to-find-more-symbols-using-the-roslyn)

Another question I asked, when I solved this issue it then solved the problem i was having here.
The problem was that i thought

```
_workspace.CurrentSolution.AddMetadataReferences(_currentProject.Id,_compilation.References);
```

updated the workspace i was working in. but it does not it returns a solution with the references added. i needed to use

```
_workspace.TryApplyChanges(referenceSolution);
```

to save it.
Thanks to Jason for answering my other question found at the link. If you post here i will mark it as an answer.